# Can we run unit test class on LWC in Windows?

Tags: salesforce

I am a beginner in Lightning Web Component(LWC) unit test. I am facing problems in testing my LWC component using lwc-jest Node.js dependency. I am kind of having a hard time in sourceApiVersion configuration. When I run the test is says

```
PS C:\Users\rdesai\Documents\GitHub\nimbusdevv> npm run test:unit

> nimbusdevv@1.0.0 test:unit C:\Users\rdesai\Documents\GitHub\nimbusdevv
> lwc-jest

error Invalid sourceApiVersion found in sfdx-project.json. Expected 47.0, found 45.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nimbusdevv@1.0.0 test:unit: `lwc-jest`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nimbusdevv@1.0.0 test:unit script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rdesai\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-21T19_21_35_974Z-debug.log
```

But when I check my current status of my salesforcedx, using`sfdx plugins --core` it shows the API version as 47

```
PS C:\Users\rdesai\Documents\GitHub\nimbusdevv> sfdx plugins --core
@oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-help 2.2.1 (core)
@oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.3 (core)
@oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.8 (core)
@oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
@oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
@oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.5 (core)
analytics 1.2.1 (core)
generator 1.1.1 (core)
salesforcedx 47.6.2 (core)
├─ salesforcedx-templates 47.6.2 (core)
└─ salesforce-alm 47.9.0 (core)

sfdx-cli 7.33.2 (core)
```

Hope someone can help me understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Hey , just check your sfdx-project.json file which is located in your project root and change api version from 45.0 to 47.0 inside the file.

Comment: when I run npm run test:unit it gives an error ```
TypeError: lwcNpmResolver.resolveLwcNpmModules is not a function```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `sfdx-project.json` file which is located in your project root and change the API version from `45.0` to `47.0` inside the file.